# How to Create Linq query Return Only Sum of Annual for not repeated Annual?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

**Problem**

How to Create a Linq query to return Only Sum of Annual for not repeated Annual?

I need to return 158 only.

I need to get distinct annual from every repeated lines if one line select it onely

I need to make this SQL query as linq return sum as 158

```
string sql = "select sum(Annual)from(select distinct(Annual) from View_MembersWithPriceList where (NonActive=0) AND ( RelatedMemberCode='" + MemberCode + "' OR MemberCode='" + MemberCode + "') AND ( Year = " + txtYear.Text + ")" + ")a";

MemberCode      Annual   RelatedMemberCode Year  NonActive
6625             108       Null            2018    0
6626             108       6625            2018    0 
6627             108       6625            2018    0
6628             50        6625            2018    0
6629             50        6625            2018    0
```

I have already `dt as Datatable` and have view `View_MembersWithPriceList`  represented in data above.

```
MemberCode      Annual   RelatedMemberCode Year  NonActive
```

`MemberCode` is integer
`Annual` is `decimal`
`RelatedMemberCode` is integer
`NonActive` is bit
`Year` is integer

I need to only return 158 only as sum  meaning return one value

and

```
string sql = "select sum(Annual)from(select distinct(Annual) from View_MembersWithPriceList where (NonActive=0) AND ( RelatedMemberCode='" + MemberCode + "' OR MemberCode='" + MemberCode + "') AND ( Year = " + txtYear.Text + ")" + ")a";
```

I need to return sql statment to linq

Comment: You should probably use a parameterized query to avoid SQL injection. I see txtbox.text so it is not internal only.

Comment: Also, I think you are trying to concatenate numbers to string without conversion. MemberCode.ToString() is sufficient.

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework?

Comment: NO I use Ado.net

Comment: What does "I need to return sql statment to linq" mean? Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you?

Comment: mean i need to make linq  from c# instead of using SQL statement